# How to set and call an instruction in php from another page

Tags: php

In calculate.php I have this code:

```
//recovery the variables from an html form
$FirstNumber=$_POST['FirstNumber'];
$SecondNumber=$_POST['SecondNumber'];
$Operation=$_POST['Operation']; //this can be '+', '-', '*', '/'.
//Now I have to call specific instructions in instructions.php (Which is the one for operations) sending to it my variables
//Now I have to recovery $result from instructions.php
echo "Result: $result";
```

Assume that in instructions.php I have this:

The page need to understand what instruction it have to do, in this case the ones from Operations sector

```
//-----Operations-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//recovery variables from calculate.php
//Tottaly doesen't know how
switch ($Operation){
case "+":
$result=$FirstNumber+$SecondNumber;
//Now I send the result in calculate.php
break;
//repeat for all the possible cases
}
//------Strings---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$control=$String;
if ($checked){
$control=$String."_Controlled";
//I have to return $control
}else {
$checked=true;
 $control=$String."_Controlled";
//return $control
}
//------Other instructions for other requests---------------------------------------------
```

So, How can I "define" and call a series of instruction from another php page?

Please don't answer me with the "meta refresh" method, it's not what I'm looking for and what I asked.

Comment: just use require_once 'operations.php' at the top of calculate.php

Comment: So I have to call the entire page?

Comment: One way is to put variables into $_SESSION, but the best method to use values in other page is to do an include of the first page:  'include('page.php')

Comment: @halojoy So, I include the page I need in the top of the page that use it, but how I send it variables and how I get the result and most important, how I say to calculate.php when to call and use operations.php?

Comment: If you have 3 variabled in first page, and you include first page on second page, then the variables are at second page, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having option to `include` the page with all the function into current page using [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) method

now you can use the page where you are getting the variables in post method and include another page on the same page at the starting point for example,

if you are getting variables on calculate.php in post method then
you can use require at the top of calculate.php

```
<?php
    require('path/to/operation.php');

    //recovery the variables from an html form
    $FirstNumber=$_POST['FirstNumber'];
    $SecondNumber=$_POST['SecondNumber'];
    $Operation=$_POST['Operation']; //this can be '+', '-', '*', '/'.

    echo "Result: ". calculate($Operation, $FirstNumber, $SecondNumber);
?>



//In your Operation.php it should be like function, and you can call that function using calculate.php to get the result.

function calculate($Operation, $FirstNumber, $SecondNumber)
    switch ($Operation){
        case "+":
            $result=$FirstNumber+$SecondNumber;
            return $result;
        break;
    }
    $control=$String;
    if ($checked){
        $control=$String."_Controlled";
        //I have to return $control
    }else {
        $checked=true;
        $control=$String."_Controlled";
        //return $control
    }
}
```

Comment: But, how to choose when use the instruction of operation.php? And how to get the result from it?

Comment: if you want to separate all the functions into one file and that file is operation.php instead of writing functions on calculate.php you can use the scenario.

Comment: Sprry, I can't understand you, you are speaking alien for me.

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include` file and can call the variable in operation.php

for example like below:

```
<?php
   include('path/to/operation.php');
   $result=$FirstNumber+$SecondNumber;
  echo $result;
?>
```